# What information does the "Express Interest" button share?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Just saw the new Express Interest button on a Stack Overflow Jobs posting, and there's a tooltip saying:

> Not ready to apply? Let this employer know you are interested, want to learn more and start talking about what’s important to you.

What information will this show to the employer?

Comment: It will show that you may be interested but you have additional questions such as time off, insurance, etc.

Comment: The question is more about which personal infos are shared with the potential employer

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I just found out that they do allow the other end to download your CV. After clicking this button I received a message starting with "Thanks for applying...". Not what I was expecting.

This is what your message will look like after you click this button;

[image]

Comment: Thats an interesting response. Employers receive 'applications' and 'interests' in the same area of the UI but the product does differentiate between the two. This employer may simply be reusing a generic response or perceived this as an application. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 18):

Your Developer Story will be included if it is at least minimally complete. That means it must have a full name, location, 2 tags, and at least 1 complete work or education entry. Alternatively you can include a resume by uploading it to your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).

[image: save resume]

Note, this is a new feature we're a/b testing so it's not available to everyone.

Comment: What happens if you express interest but then remove it after couple of minutes?

Comment: @PeterHaddad if you click 'undo', your info won't be submitted to the employer. The undo period is 5 minutes.

Comment: I recently expressed interest in a job and the message sent to the employer contained a really old resume. How do I know which resume will be included with the message?

Comment: @chaptuck you can check the resume you have saved (and change it) under your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).